# IntelliJ run configuration per git branch

Tags: git, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to have a specific run configuration in intellij per git branch. I know I could probably add the .idea/runConfigurations folder to git but I want to avoid that at all cost because my runs contain some stuff like my password. I also want to avoid using an environmental variable for the password. I'm also using gradle if that helps.

Comment: Sounds like conflicting wishes. IDEA won't be able to help you here, I think. You could probably write a gradle task that figures out your current branch and does something different depending on it.

Answer (score 1):

[gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin) allows to [define Run/Debug configurations](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.1#runconfigurations) using DSL. They will be created automatically after the project import and you can use the powers of Gradle to store passwords locally in some secure way.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that IntelliJ restores the previous run configuration that was used on the branch. From an old [IntelliJ blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/10/intellij-idea-2017-3-vcs-enhancements-and-more/) from 2017 it is mentioned that run configuration is considered a part of the workspace.

> When you switch between branches, the IDE preserves your workspace: the opened files, the current run configuration, and the breakpoints.

So locally simply change or add a new configuration on another branch and when you switch branches the old configuration should be restored automatically.